# How to order ExecStop= execution when overriding a systemd service?

Tags: debian, systemd

I'm attempting to add functionality to a systemd service (*user-runtime-dir@.service*) using an override file. The trouble I'm having is that I need the new functionality to always run "inside" the old functionality, i.e., after the *ExecStart=* and before the *ExecStop=* of the original service (since it mounts a filesystem on the directory created by the old functionality, then unmounts it before that directory is deleted).

The former is easy enough, since I can use *ExecStartPost=* to ensure the proper ordering. But there isn't an *ExecStopPre=*, and if I just use *ExecStop=*, there's no guarantee of ordering, and in practice it turns out wrong.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: (I have considered the idea of replacing the unit entirely by placing a modified file in */etc/systemd/system*, but I'd prefer not to take up the local customization path in a distributable package.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any workarounds for this?

If you need explicit ordering, you can *replace* the existing `ExecStop` functionality in the override.  So e.g., if the original unit file had:

```
ExecStop=/path/to/script1
```

In your drop-in override, you could have:

```
ExecStop=
ExecStop=/path/to/my_additional_script
ExecStop=/path/to/script1
```

The empty `ExecStop=` clears out any existing entries.

Alternately, instead of using `ExecStop`, it may be possible to implement your logic as separate units using appropriate dependencies (`Requires`/`Before`/`After`/etc).